# Angularjs ng-attr-title not working in chrome browser

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

I am using ng-table to display all values in table grid view. I want to display some messages when user hover the cell. So I am using ng-attr-title as a tool-tip. It's working in firfox, but it's not working in google chrome web browser.

`Sample`[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuDgwod8z8sItnzAL2Ix?p=preview)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems we have discuss it in other Question [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568156/how-to-bind-title-attribute-value-in-ng-table/30568601#30568601).  Use Div there for resolving this issue.

I have Edited your HTML BLOCK:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/0.10.0/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ng-table/0.3.3/ng-table.min.js"></script>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table" ng-controller="ctrl">
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="foo in data">
                <td data-title="'Name'">{{foo.name}}</td>
                <td data-title="'Age'">{{foo.age}}</td>
                <td ng-attr-title="{{foo.Desc}}" data-title="'Remarks'" >
                    <div ng-attr-title="{{foo.Desc}}">{{foo.Desc | limitTo: 15 }} {{foo.Desc.length > 15 ? '...' : ''}}</div>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Complete Code with Script see this [PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/OuDgwod8z8sItnzAL2Ix?p=preview)

Answer (score 2):

That's because Angular turns it into `data-title="Something"`. You can use CSS to display the data-title attribute, or alternatively you can use `title="{{ 'Something' }}` if you want the HTML title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

this is what happens when you do multiple things for the same objective.

Choose one way and you can defiantly achieve what you want to.

**ng-attr-title:**:

```
<td ng-attr-title="{{foo.Desc}}" >
                  {{foo.Desc | limitTo: 15 }} {{foo.Desc.length > 15 ? '...' : ''}}
                </td>
```

just **title**:

```
<td title="{{foo.Desc}}" >
                      {{foo.Desc | limitTo: 15 }} {{foo.Desc.length > 15 ? '...' : ''}}
                    </td>
```

Plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/vinoKnLgCMRUMMCLO6X3?p=preview

Answer (score -4):

Replace `ng-attr-title` with `title`.