# AngularJS - Multiple {{ }} in title attribute in TD element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, jquery-ui-tooltip

I have a problem to display a tooltip with the title attribute with AngularJS with multipe {{ }}.
I'm making kind of a calendar.

I have this :

```
        <tr ng-repeat="horaire in triPlan(planning)">
            <td>A</td>
            <td class="abraca" ng-click="selectionHoraire(horaire)" ng-repeat="rdv in horaire" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
            title="{{rdv.nom}} is {{rdv.age}} year old">{{rdv.nom}}</td>
        </tr>
```

But when I hover the TD element, it displays this " {{rdv.nom}} is {{rdv.age}} year old ". And if I put only one {{ expression }} in the title attribute, it works perfectly.

How put multiple {{ }} expressions in this title attribute ?

**UPDATE : PROBLEM SOLVED**

You can see in the answers and comments below that I use the 1.6.4 AngularJS Version.

The `ng-attr-title` don't work for me in a `ng-repeat` itself inside a `ng-repeat`. So, I don't know really why but after some tests, I put this line code :

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

And I was surprised to see that it works !! `title="{{rdv.nom}} is {{rdv.age}} year old">{{rdv.nom}}`

There some differences between the version, I don't know why in a older version it works and in a newer it doesn't.

FINALLY the result to make it works, thanks to @georgeawg.
It's to combine the two or more interpolation in only one (The text is in French, don't worry) :

```
title="{{rdv.nom+' a l\'âge :  '+rdv.age+' et vient pour : '+rdv.text}}"
```

Thanks everyone !

Comment: Angular version?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get AngularJS to bind to the title attribute of an A tag?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230868/how-do-you-get-angularjs-to-bind-to-the-title-attribute-of-an-a-tag)

Comment: I have the 10 digest aborting error so it's difficult to find an error about the title. (When I let the title attribute empty, the aborting error is still here but no matter).

My Angular version is 1.6.4

Comment: When you mix jQuery and Angular, you ask for problems. Consider using [UI-Bootstrap tooltips](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#tooltip) which are properly integrated with the AngularJS framework and its digest cycle.

Comment: Try combing the two interpolations into one: `{{rdv.nom+' is '+rdv.age+' year old'}}`.

Comment: @georgeawg Omg, you are my saver. I didn't know that we can do this. And its WORKS perfectly ! I have to say that I love you..
Seriously, thanks a lot, I gonna EDIT the first ask to explain the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine the two interpolations into one:

```
<!-- BEFORE
<tr ng-repeat="horaire in triPlan(planning)">
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="abraca" ng-click="selectionHoraire(horaire)" ng-repeat="rdv in horaire" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
    title="{{rdv.nom}} is {{rdv.age}} year old">{{rdv.nom}}</td>
</tr>
-->

<!--AFTER -->
<tr ng-repeat="horaire in triPlan(planning)">
    <td>A</td>
    <td class="abraca" ng-click="selectionHoraire(horaire)" ng-repeat="rdv in horaire" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
    title="{{rdv.nom+' is '+rdv.age+' year old'}}">{{rdv.nom}}</td>
</tr>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS Developer Guide - Expressions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Answer (score 3):

Use `ng-attr-title`.
From the [angularJS documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation):

> Web browsers are sometimes picky about what values they consider valid for attributes.
>
> If an attribute with a binding is prefixed with the ngAttr prefix (denormalized as ng-attr-) then during the binding it will be applied to the corresponding unprefixed attribute. This allows you to bind to attributes that would otherwise be eagerly processed by browsers...

```
<td class="abraca" ng-click="selectionHoraire(horaire)" 
    ng-repeat="rdv in horaire" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" 
        ng-attr-title="{{rdv.nom}} is {{rdv.age}} year old">{{rdv.nom}}</td>
```

Comment: yes exactly, you will have to write something like `<!-- example -->
<a ng-attr-title="{{}}"></a>`

Comment: @Krakito, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30589402/angularjs-ng-attr-title-not-working-in-chrome-browser) may help?

Comment: @Dragoş Paul Marinescu I try few things with your redirection.
And, I see that the angular version is really important. I'm using the angular.js 1.6.4 version and it doesnt work, and for the angular.min.js of 1.2.9 version works perfectly.

Comment: @Krakito, here's a working fiddle with angular 1.6.4: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/1wb3sd87/). What browser are you using?

Comment: @Dragoş Paul Marinescu I try your code on my html page and it's working perfectly... maybe it's my table that confusing this work... because when i put the ng-attr-title on my TD element, so no tooltip appear when hover.
I was on Chrome but after you asked I tried on Firefox and it's the exactly same result on both...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, 
I found out something thanks to @Dragos Paul Marinescu redirection question.

I found out that if I use the angular.js of the version 1.6.4. The tooltip don't display correctly, but if I use the angular.min of the version 1.2.9, its works perfectly...

I had this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
```

And if I add this in my HTML :

```
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.9/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Now it works perfectly... Thanks...But I really don't understand why it makes this. Why a higher version don't make the tooltip works ?
And it's a dirty way I think to put this two lines together to make my app works...

Comment: It means they changed something in a later version and you need to find out what. What you're doing now probably isn't viable with this new change. It's not a good idea to downgrade to get the functionality working, it's best to make it work on the latest version to avoid issues down the line.